# How to put values from array in td elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm very new to programming, especially to JavaScript and I encounter some problem with putting some values from an array to td elements.
I want to grab the nodeValue from td Elements performe some calculation on it and put it back in some other td-elements. The first part works fine, but I didn't get it right to put the values back from the array in other td elements. 
I always get the warning in the console.:

> TypeError:
>   document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName(...).item(...) is
>   null

What do I wrong? The relevant code:

```
        for (i = 0; i <= getPreis.length; i++) {
        priceNumber += 1;
        newElement += 1;
    }
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    // create array element
    var oldPrice = [];
    // get all td elements in id "originalPrice"
    var getPreis = document.getElementById('originalPrice').getElementsByTagName('td');
    // determine number of td elements
    for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
        oldPrice.push(getPreis[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }


    // get all td elements in id "listNewPrice"
    var putPreis = document.getElementById('listNewPrice').getElementsByTagName('td');
    // set index of item
    var newElement = 0;
    // set index for array
    var priceNumber = 0;
    // perform operation on array element
    var newPrice = oldPrice[priceNumber] * 0.94;

/* it got problems with this for loop
   here i want to loop through all td elements in tr "listNewPrice" and put the values from the array in there */
    for (i = 0; i <= getPreis.length; i++) {
        priceNumber += 1;
        newElement += 1;
    }

        document.getElementById("listNewPrice").getElementsByTagName('td').item(newElement).innerHTML = newPrice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="originalPrice">
        <td>22.50</td>
        <td>45.00</td>
        <td>75.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="listNewPrice">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the calculation and assignment of the result to the `td` element inside your loop as you are using incrementing index values that get calculated inside the for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
    var newPrice = oldPrice[priceNumber] * 0.94;
    document.getElementById("listNewPrice").getElementsByTagName('td').item(newElement).innerHTML = newPrice;
    priceNumber += 1;
    newElement += 1;
}
```

In your example `newElement === 2` after the for loop then you try and get the item at index 2 of the array of `td` elements which doesn't exist. Hence the error

> document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName(...).item(...) is null

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5hbj562/1/)

Comment: Hey spaceman, thanks a lot for your good explanation. Now it works. Tried hours before...

Comment: That code is still giving an error. Reason is it loops 4 times instead of 3... use: for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to be reading numeric data out of the original table and performing calculations on it, you'll need to ensure that you are properly parsing the values as numbers instead of strings.

You can do this by using the [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function when reading in your values :

```
for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
    // Read in the actual values (so they will be usable in calculations)
    oldPrice.push(parseFloat(getPreis[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
}
```

Then when updating your values, just perform the operation backwards (i.e. iterate through your loop and set the values of each node) :

```
// determine number of td elements
for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
    putPreis[i].innerHTML = oldPrice[i] * 0.94;
}
```

Both of these changes will allow you to greatly simplify your existing code :

```
function myFunction() {
    // create array element
    var oldPrice = [];
    // get all td elements in id "originalPrice"
    var getPreis = document.getElementById('originalPrice').getElementsByTagName('td');
    // determine number of td elements
    for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
        oldPrice.push(parseFloat(getPreis[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
    }
    // get all td elements in id "listNewPrice"
    var putPreis = document.getElementById('listNewPrice').getElementsByTagName('td');

    // update your values
    for (i = 0; i < getPreis.length; i++) {
        putPreis[i].innerHTML = oldPrice[i] * 0.94;
    }
}
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/lotura/1/edit?html,js,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Hi Rion, thanks a lot for this AWESOME explanation. This helps me a lot for improving my JavaScript-skills.